# Make ms-edge Window full screen (F11, normally) via powershell script

Tags: powershell, microsoft-edge

I'm trying to make ms-edge Window full screen (F11, normally) via powershell script.

This is an example of the powershell script I'm using to start edge:

```
Start-Process -FilePath msedge -ArgumentList '--new-window www.google.com'
```

This works fine.  However, I want the edge window to be full-screen, like what happens when you press F11 while in the browser.  This action cannot be dependent on the windows user or individual user ms-edge profile settings.  I need it to be done from the script - if that is possible - so the action is the same for all users when they run the script.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Start-Process msedge.exe https:\\google.com -WindowStyle Maximized
```

Comment: Thank you - I actually need it both Maximized AND Full Screen.  You provided half of the answer!

Comment: Note that maximizing a window, which is a Windows shell concept, is not the same as the Edge (Chromium)-specific full-screen mode, which hides the title bar.

Comment: Christian: Yes.... I'm trying to A) Open the Window, B) Maximize the window and C) remove the title bar    So three things, really.   The first two are windows-type functions, the third is something from Edge.

Comment: Understood, @CDK19, but your question is only about C) and this answer doesn't address C), so I think it is confusing to have this answer be the accepted one. As a an aside: at least older versions of Edge (102.0.1245.33) do _not_ honor `-WindowStyle Maximized` and instead use the window state from the previous session / the active window in the current session. The current version of _Chrome_ does seem to honor `-WindowStyle Maximized`, but not any other "styles" (states), such as `-WindowStyle Normal`. Perhaps more recent / future Edge versions already do / exhibit this behavior too.

Answer (score 3):

if you're looking to start it in *Full Screen* mode, you can use the `start-fullscreen` switch.

- `--start-fullscreen`.

So, it would be:

```
Start-Process -FilePath "msedge.exe" -ArgumentList '--new-window www.google.com --start-fullscreen'
```

---

*Here are the [content switches / source](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/master:content/public/common/content_switches.cc;l=716?q=start-fullscreen&ss=chromium) you can use, where `start-fullscreen` is shown as well.*

Comment: Thank you - I actually need it both Maximized AND Full Screen.  You provided half of the answer!

Comment: @CDK19, glad it helped. Quick note, *Full Screen* mode will be maximized.

Comment: This seems to be the right approach, but my Edge version 102.0.1245.33 on W10 2H12 only honors `--new-window`, not also `--start-fullscreen` - any idea why?

Comment: @mklement0, nothing off top of my head. Wonder what OP is on now. Let me check my edge version lol read your OS build for some reason: 102.0.1245.33

Comment: same stable edge version just on 20H2, not sure where the issue lies. Unless that header file is missing

Comment: @CDK19, I encourage you to mark Christian's post as the answer. Out of curiosity, what is your OS build and Edge version?

Comment: Yeah, I jumped the gun on verifying the solution.    --new-window works fine.  the --start-fullscreen does not work.   My script is:  `Start-Process -FilePath msedge -Argumentlist '--new-window --start-fullscreen https://example.com'` I am using Version 10 Pro OS Build 19042.1708,   Edge Version 102.0.1245.33 (Official build) (64-bit)

Comment: @CDK19, what about: `[System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version`? What does that give you

Comment: Major  Minor  Build  Revision
-----  -----  -----  --------
10     0      19042  0

Comment: @CDK19, does `start msedge.exe -ArgumentList '--kiosk www.google.com --edge-kiosk-type=fullscreen --new-window'` work for you? If it does, keep in mind that the option to leave *full screen* won't be available though F11.

Comment: Abraham: I played around some more: the problem only surfaces _intermittently_, with Edge already running, and killing any `msedge` processes before trying again fixes the problem. In other words: your solution _typically_ works, and therefore I think it should be the accepted answer, given that the question only asks about full-screen mode, not also about putting the window into the maximized state when not in full-screen mode. /cc @CDK19

Comment: @mklement0, I figured it was odd that it wasn't working for y'all. I just replicated the same issue on my win11 box; closing all edge instances and running the code opened it in full screen, just not while it was already opened. On my previous work comp. I was able to do it regardless of if it was already opened. Thank you for the follow up.

Comment: Interesting; I don't have access to W11, but on my W10 machine the problem of not opening in full-screen mode only _sometimes_ happens when Edge is already open (if it isn't, it _never_ happens).

Comment: This is now the correct answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73986856/1851270

Answer (score 2):

I also recently wanted to open a web page in full-screen mode simply via a shortcut in autostart.

`--start-fullscreen` did not work, for whatever reason.

`--kiosk www.google.com --edge-kiosk-type=fullscreen` worked, but Edge is started in private mode and some functions no longer work.

Now I found out that `--start-fullscreen` does not work in connection with the "startup boost" of Edge. **As soon as this is switched off in the settings, the parameter works again.**